# significance of int position in getView

Tags: java, android

What is the significance of position attribute in the getView function of array adapter?I am stuck with an example where getView is called again and again with the value 0 whereas the list passed to it has multiple elements.
Please help

```
private ArrayAdapter<Connection> buildConnectionAdapter(final ArrayList<Connection> connectionList) {
        ArrayAdapter<Connection> attachmentadapter = new ArrayAdapter<Connection>(this, R.layout.text_view, R.id.dummy, connectionList) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final String value;
                Connection obj = connectionList.get(position);
                value = obj.getValue();
                TextView tv = new TextView(UserGlobalAppSettings.this);
                SpannableString str = makeLinkSpan(value, new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    }
                });
                str.setSpan(new URLSpan(""), 0, value.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                tv.setText(str);
                tv.setTag(obj);
                return tv;
            }
        };
        return attachmentadapter;

    }
```

The Layout is like this

```
  <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/im_services_list"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
                    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer...We are not suppose to use two scrollable items within each other according to google philosophy!!!!...but had alrteady written a lot of code annd time so did this!!...

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        // pre-condition
        return;
    }
    int totalHeight = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        listItem.measure(0, 0);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? Did you create a listView/scrollView inside your listView ?

Comment: The method above works fine for calculating the size of the list-view and setting it manually

Comment: Such a thing (putting a scrollView/listView withing a scrollView/listView ) is not recommended . Watch the lecture "the world of listView" . I think they talk about it in the end.

Answer (score 0):

The position attribute defines the position of item clicked in the list/spinner, If your list shows 0 items even if a list of multiple items is being correctly passed i would suggest checking getcount method of the adapter, whether it returns the count of the list being passed or not.

Comment: Tried that! dosent work.Somehow the getView is called multiple times with the same position value=0.Have overridden the getCount method as well.

Comment: in the get count add yourlist.length in return statement and it happens getview runs multiple times for the same position.